# How to select all stateid and state name from this inspect element

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup

i want to select all value name from below code and their state id by beautifulsoup.
please anyone tell how to write beautifulsoup script to scrap all stateid and state name

```
    <select id="stateId" class="states" name="state" required="required">
<option value="">Select State</option>
<option value="Andaman and Nicobar Islands" stateid="1">Andaman and Nicobar Islands</option>
<option value="Andhra Pradesh" stateid="2">Andhra Pradesh</option>
<option value="Arunachal Pradesh" stateid="3">Arunachal Pradesh</option>
<option value="Assam" stateid="4">Assam</option>
<option value="Bihar" stateid="5">Bihar</option>
<option value="Chandigarh" stateid="6">Chandigarh</option>
<option value="Chhattisgarh" stateid="7">Chhattisgarh</option>
<option value="Dadra and Nagar Haveli" stateid="8">Dadra and Nagar Haveli</option>
<option value="Daman and Diu" stateid="9">Daman and Diu</option>
<option value="Delhi" stateid="10">Delhi</option>
<option value="Goa" stateid="11">Goa</option>
<option value="Gujarat" stateid="12">Gujarat</option>
<option value="Haryana" stateid="13">Haryana</option>
<option value="Himachal Pradesh" stateid="14">Himachal Pradesh</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this, I designed a list comprehension that cycled through all "option" elements using `findAll` and got their state ID and state name:

```
[(x["stateid"], x["value"]) for x in bs.findAll("option") if x["value"] != ""]
```

I used the list comprehension like this:

```
>>> import bs4
>>> bs = bs4.BeautifulSoup(<your text>)
>>> [(x["stateid"], x["value"]) for x in bs.findAll("option") if x["value"] != ""]
[('1', 'Andaman and Nicobar Islands'), ('2', 'Andhra Pradesh'), ('3', 'Arunachal Pradesh'), ('4', 'Assam'), ('5', 'Bihar'), ('6', 'Chandigarh'), ('7', 'Chhattisgarh'), ('8', 'Dadra and Nagar Haveli'), ('9', 'Daman and Diu'), ('10', 'Delhi'), ('11', 'Goa'), ('12', 'Gujarat'), ('13', 'Haryana'), ('14', 'Himachal Pradesh')]
```

It returns a list of tuples, with the first element of each being the state ID and the second being the state name. It also omits the blank value at the beginning by using `if x["value"] != ""`.

Answer (score 0):

To improve what OrangeFlash81 suggested, you can use `find_all()` passing the `value=lambda x: x` to avoid extracting the first "empty" option:

```
select = soup.find("select", id="stateId")
options = [(option["stateid"], option["value"]) 
           for option in select.find_all("option", value=lambda x: x)]
print(options)
```

Or, with a [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) skipping the first "empty" option by slicing the resultset:

```
options = [(option["stateid"], option["value"])
           for option in soup.select("#stateId option")[1:]]
print(options)
```